# Post form without a button

Tags: asp.net, forms

I was exploring the search box on the Apple website and noticed it doesn't have a input type="submit" to post the form, even when Javascript is disabled.

```
<form action="/search/" method="post" class="search" id="g-search">
    <div class="sp-label">
        <label for="sp-searchtext">Search</label>
        <input type="text" name="q" id="sp-searchtext" accesskey="s">
     </div>
 </form>
```

Having never really explored it, I take it from this it means you can post a form without needing a submit button, it just relies on the user pressing the return key.

Two questions: 1) Is this compatible across all browsers? So in IE 7 will pressing return still work?; 2) Is there a way to do this in ASP.NET without using an asp:button? I will probably have it inside a placeholder (where I would conventionally use defaultButton to allow for multiple forms on the page) but if I can get rid of the button altogether then that's a plus.

Comment: I wonder whether we can use __doPostBack('page' , ''); something like this and call this on key enter but again it use Javascript...:(

Answer (score 3):

yes of course it is possible to do it in anyway you want.

The simpler thing is to have an onclick event that calls a function that does the submit like this:

JQuery:

```
$('#id_of_form').submit()
```

javascript:

```
document.name_of_my_form.submit();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('id_of_my_form').submit();
```

so simple :)

Comment: Is there a way which doesn't rely on Javascript? I appreciate using .net I am probably reliant on it anyway but I would be keen to know the possibilities without the use of JS.

Comment: whats wrong with javascript? Is there any website now that doesnt use it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Javascript per se, I was simply curious to find out that a form could be posted without it and without a button. Interestingly I created a dummy form (not asp) with only an input type=text. Hitting return would post this to the action on the form. However, doing the same on an aspx page (letting it use the default asp.net form) seemed to somehow stop this working, even with JS off.